NetOffice Custom TaskPane is not loading
I am trialing the NetOffice C# COMAddins Examples projects with Taskpanes. The addins shows properly in Word and Powerpoint projects with respectfull Ribbon buttons. Additionally, I have decorated the SamplePane with ComVisible, Guid and ProgId as per other posts. The issue is that the taskpane still does not show. When powershell command is run
New-Object -ComObject "PowerPoint02AddinCS4.SamplePane"

It generates the error : The system cannot find the file specified (Exception on from HRESULT:0x80070002)
what else I am missing?
